# Spring Kafka listener method - logging input record

Tags: logging, spring-kafka

I am using `spring-kafka` and my `@KafkaListener` method has an argument annotated with `@org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload` like below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic")
public void consumeTrigger(@Payload InputDTO InputDTO) {
   ...
}
```

Input is in json format and I am using `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer` as value-deserializer. Everything is good but I need to log the input json received. Is there such facility that `spring-kafka` and if not is there any alternative apart of providing custom JsonDeserializer?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no logging in the deserializer; you could simply wrap the `JsonDeserializer` in your own and call it's `deserialize()` after logging; just be sure to delegate the `configure()` method too.